# VScode Solidity extension - not finding openzepplin imports

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, openzeppelin, hardhat

I'm trying to get started with what should be a very simple Solidity contract but VSCode is giving me a hard time.
I'm using Juan Blancos solidity plugin but VSCode cannot find openzepplin imports

`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";`

The error is:

> Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Even though vscode shows red squigglies I can compile successfully via **hardhat compile**.

If I change the path to

`import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";`

VScode stops complaining but then I cannot compile via hardhard, with the error being:

> Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.

My VSCode settings for Solidity extension for both User and Workspace are:

```
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "contracts",
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules"
```

Which corresponds to my project structure

```
root 
 |_ contracts
    |_ MyToken.sol
 |_ node_modules
    |_ @openzepplin
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#openzeppelin) and have done extensive researching but unfortunately can't get it to working.

Comment: I'm trying to import it VScode using GitHub. `import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";` But it's giving me an error `This contract not found and File import callback not supported`. Using `Juan Blanco` extension for `Solidity`.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issues.
[image]
Go to the VSCode Settings (Workspace) and type packageDefaultDependencies in the seachbar.
[image]

Then click the `Edit in settings.json` at the bottom.
[image]

Add this line to the `settings.json` file

```
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules",
```

Then the red lines will be removed.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
```

I had same issue.  I had multiple folders added in the `unnamed` workspace. After removing all other folders and keeping only one project folder resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Linting issues
If you see something along the lines of:

```
ParserError: Source "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File not found.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

In your vscode, these and be safely ignored. However you can also add to your settings to ignore these.

1. Create a .vscode folder at the root of your project.
2. Create a file called settings.json
   Add the following code:

```
{
  "solidity.remappings": [
    "@chainlink/=/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2",
    "@openzeppelin/=/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2"
  ]
}
```

Or whatever version your @chainlink and @openzeppelin contracts need. For example:
[image]

[For more information see here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/blob/main/chronological-issues-from-video.md)