# Solidity importing problem on VSCode (WSL2) and Brownie

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain, solidity, brownie

I'm working with a Solidity using Brownie Framework running on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 host machine.

And I have to import chainlink dependecies to my project, so I have the following importors

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
```

To get them work properly I added the folling code to brownie-config.yaml

```
dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
```

So running brownie compile, the compiler works just fine, however visual studio code complains about the imports

[Vscode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/260Ww.png)

Additional Info: I'm using the romote compiler version, and if I change it to "localNodeModule" Vscode stops complaining about the import but it starts to complain about solidity version:

[Solidity error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5bl2.png)

And I not able to compile the project anymore.

I read some other post like this one: [VScode Solidity extension - not finding openzepplin imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314540/vscode-solidity-extension-not-finding-openzepplin-imports) with similar problems, but unfornatelly the problems still unresolve.

Comment: You need to configure vscode solidity to be able to find your chainlink contract. You can [point it at your `node_modules`](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#project-structure) (if you install chainlink via npm) or [try the freshly added support for remappings to make it use packages installed by Brownie](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/issues/183#issuecomment-929197969).

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Brownie stores library contract data (Chainlink, OpenZeppelin, other dependencies) inside of `Users/$yourUsername/.brownie/packages`. That's on Mac at least. If you're on Windows, look for a `.brownie` directory.

To point the Ethereum VS Code extension to these files, you can add a Solidity remapping. This can be done by adding the following:

```
"solidity.remappings": [
    "@openzeppelin/=/Users/rafi/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0"
  ]
```

to your `settings.json` file in VS Code. After restarting VS Code, the warning/error should disappear!

Check out the [readme](http://%22solidity.remappings%22:%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%22@chainlink/=/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2%22,%20%20%20%20%20%22@openzeppelin/=/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2%22%20%20%20%5D) for the Ethereum VS Code extension for more info.

Comment: Thank you Rafi! Solved the problem for me too.

Comment: how did you not get an upvote for this? criminal! upvoted

Answer (score 0):

In my case even the remapping in the `brownie-config.yaml` did not work, but specifying the local path directly in the import did work. Not sure why (would be interested to figure it out).

Not working:

```
// in contract
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

```
// in brownie-config.yaml
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=/Users/<your-user>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

Working:

```
// in contract
import "/Users/filippomassarelli/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing: npm install @chainlink/contracts --save

and in the yaml file doing:[image]